# How to add property to object in PHP >= 5.3 strict mode without generating error

Tags: php, class

This has to be simple, but I can't seem to find an answer....

I have a generic stdClass object `$foo` with no properties.  I want to add a new property `$bar` to it that's not already defined. If I do this:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = '1234';
```

PHP in strict mode complains.

What is the proper way (outside of the class declaration) to add a property to an already instantiated object?

NOTE: I want the solution to work with the generic PHP object of type stdClass.

A little background on this issue.  I'm decoding a json string which is an array of json objects.  `json_decode()` generates an array of StdClass object.  I need to manipulate these objects and add a property to each one.

Comment: Try passing `TRUE` as a 2nd parameter to `json_decode`.  It'll give you an associative array instead of an array of objects.

Comment: PHP in strict mode does not complain about that. http://3v4l.org/kn0hi

Comment: I don't know why this has been closed since this is a perfectly valid question. I have an exact similar question right now.

Comment: Can any of the people who've upvoted this question and its answers explain what exactly the supposed error here is? Even [the recently passed RFC which will make dynamic properties an error _in PHP 9.0_](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties) explicitly allows them on stdClass, because that's kind of the point of it. I can only think there is actually some "code style" tool which people are blindly "tricking" with the answers below.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

If you absolutely have to add the property to the object, I believe you could cast it as an array, add your property (as a new array key), then cast it back as an object.  The only time you run into `stdClass` objects (I believe) is when you cast an array as an object or when you create a new `stdClass` object from scratch (and of course when you `json_decode()` something - silly me for forgetting!).

Instead of:

```
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->bar = '1234';
```

You'd do:

```
$foo = array('bar' => '1234');
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

Or if you already had an existing stdClass object:

```
$foo = (array)$foo;
$foo['bar'] = '1234';
$foo = (object)$foo;
```

Also as a 1 liner:

```
$foo = (object) array_merge( (array)$foo, array( 'bar' => '1234' ) );
```

Comment: One place you encounter StdClass is when you decode json, which is pretty common.

Comment: @Ray I'm shaking my head in sadness that I didn't think of mentioning that.  =)

Comment: Your solution works, but it hurts my OO heart :) Was hoping for some type of flashy reflection kung foo or something...  Going to keep the question open a bit longer and hope for some little known PHP magic.

Comment: @Ray hehehe... I wish I had something more elegant for you.  Incidentally, explicitly setting `error_reporting(E_STRICT);` on `PHP 5.3.15-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch`, I don't get any errors or notices when attempting to set a non-existent property on a stdClass object.  What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Ha, nearly three years later and I get a drive-by downvote with no explanation for some reason.  Thank you.

Comment: I love your humility, @Crontab. People are so defensive. +1

Answer (score 159):

Do it like this:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->{"bar"} = '1234';
```

now try:

```
echo $foo->bar; // should display 1234
```

Comment: Works as charm. This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: How do you add a property to a field on an object using this syntax?

Comment: 'Attempt to assign property of non-object' Error in Laravel

Comment: even the "bar" string can be in a variable: $foo->{$any_variable} = '1234';

Comment: This should definitively be the accepted answer, as it keeps the object reference intact (which in my case was crucial).

Comment: This makes no sense. `$foo->{"bar"}` is just a different syntax for `$foo->bar`, which I'm pretty sure will be handled exactly the same _by the compiler_ before the code is ever run, and any decent static analysis tool should treat it the same way too. Can anyone explain what error this supposedly avoids?

Comment: Part of the question says “ PHP in strict mode complains.

What is the proper way (outside of the class declaration) to add a property to an already instantiated object?

NOTE: I want the solution to work with the generic PHP object of type stdClass.”

Answer (score 11):

If you want to edit the decoded JSON, try getting it as an associative array instead of an array of objects.

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 9):

This is another way:

```
$foo = (object)null; //create an empty object
$foo->bar = "12345";

echo $foo->bar; //12345
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use magic methods __Set and __get. Simple example:

```
class Foo
{
    //This array stores your properties
private $content = array();

public function __set($key, $value)
{
            //Perform data validation here before inserting data
    $this->content[$key] = $value;
    return $this;
}

public function __get($value)
{       //You might want to check that the data exists here
    return $this->$content[$value];
}

}
```

Of course, don't use this example as this : no security at all :)

EDIT : seen your comments, here could be an alternative based on reflection and a decorator :

```
 class Foo
 {
private $content = array();
private $stdInstance;

public function __construct($stdInstance)
{
    $this->stdInstance = $stdInstance;
}

public function __set($key, $value)
{
    //Reflection for the stdClass object
    $ref = new ReflectionClass($this->stdInstance);
    //Fetch the props of the object

    $props = $ref->getProperties();

    if (in_array($key, $props)) {
        $this->stdInstance->$key = $value;
    } else {
        $this->content[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}

public function __get($value)
{
    //Search first your array as it is faster than using reflection
    if (array_key_exists($value, $this->content))
    {
        return $this->content[$value];
    } else {
        $ref = new ReflectionClass($this->stdInstance);

        //Fetch the props of the object
        $props = $ref->getProperties();

        if (in_array($value, $props)) {

        return $this->stdInstance->$value;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('No prop in here...');
    }
}
 }
}
```

PS : I didn't test my code, just the general idea...

Comment: Benjamin, I want to use PHP's generic object class:  StdClass.  I cannot modify this class.

Comment: Ray, I updated my answer with a solution corresponding to your need, but it's heavy :-/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether its the newer version of php, but this works. I'm using php 5.6

```
    <?php
    class Person
    {
       public $name;

       public function save()
       {
          print_r($this);
       }
    }

   $p = new Person;
   $p->name = "Ganga";
   $p->age = 23;

   $p->save();
```

This is the result. The save method actually gets the new property

```
    Person Object
    (
       [name] => Ganga
       [age] => 23
    )
```

Comment: I ran several test for the code across php versions and result shows it only works for php 5 and above. any version below php5 throws an error.

Answer (score -8):

Yes,  is possible to dynamically add properties to a PHP object.

This is useful when a partial object is received from javascript.

JAVASCRIPT side:

```
var myObject = { name = "myName" };
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "index.php",
    data: myObject, dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
}).success(function(datareceived){
    if(datareceived.id >= 0 ) { /* the id property has dynamically added on server side via PHP */ }
});
```

PHP side:

```
$requestString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myObject = json_decode($requestString); // same object as was sent in the ajax call
$myObject->id = 30; // This will dynamicaly add the id property to the myObject object
```

OR JUST SEND A DUMMY PROPERTY from javascript that you will fill in PHP.

Comment: I think sending a dummy property from JS and fill in on PHP side is the easiest smarter solution. Thanks!

Comment: o_O    O_o    o_O    O_o