# Is this a bug or a coding error?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on a page [events] and it's doing the weirdest thing. I'm trying to create a delete function where it sets a field name (deleted) to 1. This means the data isn't fully lost, the get-events ajax page gets events where deleted = 0.

However, when you click the button it gives a success message, but doesn't delete. I've tested the SQL statement in SQLyog to make sure my SQL was right and it was. I checked the PHP error log and there were no errors.. everything matches and it should work fine, if I changed my SQL statement from:

```
UPDATE events SET deleted = 1 WHERE eventid = :eventid
```

to:

```
UPDATE 1events SET deleted = 1 WHERE eventid = :eventid
```

then it springs up an error so everything is being read.. it's just not doing it..

here's my class construct:

```
Class Events{
    public function __construct($EventId = null, $Array = null) {
        if (isset($EventId)) {

            $database = new Connection();
            $database = $database->Connect();

            $statement = $database->Prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE EventId = :EventId");
            $statement->execute(array("EventId" => $EventId));
            $Array = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }

        if (isset($Array)) {
            foreach ($Array as $Key => $Value) {
                $this->$Key = $Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

here's my delete function:

```
public function DeleteEvent() {
    try {
        $database = new Connection();
        $database = $database->Connect();

        $statement = $database->Prepare("UPDATE events SET deleted = 1 WHERE EventId = :EventId");
        $statement->execute(array("EventId" => $this->EventId ));
        $this->Success = 1;
        $this->Message = 'Event Deleted';

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->Success = 0;
        $this->Message = "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

my delete ajax:

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/galaxy-connect.php';

  $a_json = array();
  $a_json_row = array();

  if (empty($_POST['EventId'])) {
    $a_json_row["success"] = 0;
    $a_json_row["message"] = 'Something Went Wrong';
  } else {
    $Event = new Events($_POST['EventId']);
    $Event->DeleteEvent($_POST);

    $a_json_row["success"] = $Event->Success;
    $a_json_row["message"] = $Event->Message;

  }

  array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
  echo json_encode($a_json);
```

is there anything wrong with my code? or is this a weird bug?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: `public function DeleteEvent()` takes no arguments, but you are passing one. Doesn't seem like it will make a difference here, but it's worth noting.

Comment: include a console.log inside your ajax success request and see if there is any kind of error.

Comment: @Xatoo there is no error..

Comment: Have you checked that the records are actually being updated. If they are then maybe the query in `get-events ajax` is bad?

Comment: You forget `$this->EventId = $EventId;` at your constructor

Comment: no he didn't, he's dynamically extending the class properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple! I was passing the data as an array when I wanted an object!

If anyone has a similar problem and finds it, double check your code converts data to an object, NOT an array :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a constructor

```
  $Event = new Events($_POST['EventId']);
```

and calling a method

```
  $Event->DeleteEvent($_POST);
```

But the method

```
 public function DeleteEvent() {
      try {
        ....
```

refers to `$this->EventId`

Either you constructor does not populate `$this->EventId` or your method does not fetch the one argument `$_POST` properly (or both ...)

The constructor of the Events class at least should look like

```
class Events {

   public function __construct($id) {
       ....

          $this->EventId = $id;
```

Comment: I've done a var_dump of the $_POST and it brings through the correct ID, it's super weird

Comment: Show your constructor of Events Class

Comment: phew, I see. And this is not generating any errors?

Comment: Could you var_dump after the `new ...`, please?

Comment: nope, everything says it all works, except it doesn't, I've checked my database and it doesn't update that field for some weird reason

Comment: could you, just as a test, define the EventID as a property prior to the `try { ...`? I assume that adding properties isn't that simple according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618349/how-to-add-property-to-object-in-php-5-3-strict-mode-without-generating-error

Comment: I did as suggested and same effect.. my original theory was it not passing the id properly but if I set the message to equal ID then it shows the id in the "success" message

Comment: is this `$Array = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` executed properly?

Comment: as in if I var_dump $statement, does it show the data?

Comment: No just `var_dump($Array)`

Comment: I var_dumped and it showed all my fields inc. deleted and everything matches up (in my database)

Comment: could you just post the var_dump here?

Comment: I can't, it exceeds the length of characters allowed :/ but I'll post the most important bits

Comment: `object(Events)[2]
      public 'EventId' => string '623' (length=3)
      public 'VenueId' => null
      public 'StatusId' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'deleted' => string '0' (length=1)`

There are other fields but they mainly consist of costs and event description.

Comment: try `$statement->execute(array("EventId" => ìntval($this->EventId) ));